# c# include personal font into program

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

In my application written in c# I use for the UI components a personal font that is not present in the standard installations of windows.

I wish include the font into the program, to show the font correct in all the pc where the program runs, but I wish avoid to install the font in the windows\fonts folder, to avoid the use of the font for other things... it's possible this?

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use non true type fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675781/use-non-true-type-fonts)

Comment: it's different, 'cause here I need to inglobe the font into the app, in the other question I have a problem USING the font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [`PrivateFontCollection`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection)